# Word to describe the satisfaction of manipulation

Tags: single-word-requests

Recently I've become interested in police interrogations, and noticed a lot of criminals seem to have a smirk or what I perceive as some form of masked enjoyment or satisfaction. It's how I would perceive my reaction to be when I know I'm getting away with being the imposter on Among Us.

Is there a word for the satisfaction or enjoyment of having gotten away with lying or manipulating, or more broadly general mischief?

Comment: I like the word *smug*: having or showing an excessive pride in oneself or one's achievements. *The perp gave a smug grin.* But while *smug* is because the perp pulled off a good lie, *smug* is pride any achievement, not only a nefarious one.

Comment: Really like smug too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think self-satisfaction in criminals is a kind of sinister self-satisfaction combined with disdain for the others, and you could name it a ***gloat***. "Gloat" is a verb, but can be used informally as a noun. It means:

> dwell on one's own success or another's misfortune with smugness or malignant pleasure.
>
> - His enemies ***gloated*** over his death. ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03UCHbVP7y5FHVu3Yy1LwPxp6S0Ww%3A1612446863634&ei=j_wbYPWRJreChbIPz7mI2AQ&q=gloat%20meaning&oq=gloat%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgcIABCxAxBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIICAAQBxAKEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB5Qj64BWJO0AWD1wwFoAHACeACAAfcDiAHFB5IBBzQuMS41LTGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab))

Comment: I'll give you it, this seems best! There's nothing specific to that exact emotion, so I'll preface it with something suggesting delinquency